# Is it possible to move Azure Ubuntu VM from resource group to classic?

Tags: azure, ubuntu-14.04

I did set up a Ubuntu VM in Azure, unfortunately using resource group deploy model. Now I find out that resource group guest OS VM cant backup or take a snapshot to the storage as one would do with a classic machine.

It did took a while to set up the Ubuntu VM, hosting an PHP web application and database, productive now.

I am a developer not a system person, is there a way like moving the storages of the resource group host into a classic environment instead of setting up a new Ubuntu VM and installing everything again?

Comment: In the meantime I got a notification from Microsoft Azure support, that " that backup of RM based VM was not available till about a week ago. It is now available, albeit in preview, so not officially supported."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While your VM is ARM-based, the underlying VHD is in blob storage. As it's just a blob, it may be copied anywhere.

You'll first need to destroy your VM (which effectively breaks the underlying lease to the VHD), but preserve the disk (e.g. don't delete the VHD).

If you don't already have a Classic storage account, you'll need to create one (you can do this via either portal, or via CLI/PowerShell).

Then copy the vhd from ARM-based storage to Classic storage. The Azure team provides AzCopy for this purpose, but you can use whatever 3rd-party tool you choose.

At this point, you should be able to create a disk from that vhd and create a Classic VM based on that disk.